# How to identify a periodic sequence in an array of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm

The main goal is to find a periodic sequence in an array with bash,for example :

{ 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4 }
or { 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4 }

which must return as identified sequence for the two example
{ 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4 } and { 2, 5, 6, 3, 4 }

I tried with a list and a sub-list made of two arrays but with no success.
I must be missing something in my loops . I think to the "tortoise and hare" algorithm as an alternative but i miss some knowledge in bash commands to implement it .

I prefer to post my second try with tortoise and hare as the first seem to be a useless try :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A array=( 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 )
declare -A found=()
loop="notfound"
tortoise=`echo ${array[0]}`
hare=`echo ${array[0]}`
found[0]=`echo ${array[0]}`
while ( $loop == "notfound" )
do
    for ((i=1;i=`echo ${#array[@]}`;i++))
    do
        if (( `echo ${array[$#]}` == $hare ))
        then
            echo "no loop found"
            exit 0
        fi
        hare=`echo ${array[$i]}`
        if (( `echo ${array[$#]}` == $hare ))
        then
            echo "no loop found"
            exit 0
        fi
        hare=`echo ${array[$(($i+1))]}`
        tortoise=`echo  ${array[$i]}`
        found[$i]=`echo  ${array[$i]}`
        if (( $hare == $tortoise ))
        then
            loop="found"
            printf "$found[@]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

I got errors on associative array needing indice

Comment: `I tried with a list and a sub-list made of two arrays but with no success i must be missing something in my loops` better to post that code here

Comment: is a perl solution okay? for example, if those two array values are printed (with a separator) into a file, say `ip.txt`.. then this would find the minimum repeating set.. `perl -lnE '$,=":"; @a=/\d+/g; for($i=1; $i<$#a/2+1; $i++){push(@b,@a[0..$i-1]) foreach (0..$#a/$i); if(@b ~~ @a){print @a[0..$i-1]; last} undef @b}' ip.txt`

Comment: can't you do this with `grep -o`? for instance: `TEST=( 1 2 3 4 5 ); echo ${TEST[@]}|grep -o "3 4"`

Comment: I dont't know in advance what is in the array , here for the test example i populate with test values 1 2 3 1 2 3 .

Comment: What *kind* of thing can be in the array? It's fairly easy to check whether a given *string of digits* consists entirely of a repeated subsequence e.g. `grep -xE '([0-9]+)(\1)+'` or to find and print it e.g. `sed -nE 's/^([0-9]+)(\1)+$/\1/p'`

Comment: It is composed of repeated sequence of integers but they can be uncomplete at the end of the array like 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2

Comment: Integers, or single decimal digits?

Comment: they could also be very long repeated sequence

Comment: there are only integers in the array  , in fact really they are only integers in ternary base 0 1 2 , with periodic sequence like the Pisano sequence 01120221 (obtained from modulo 3 reduction on Fibonacci sequence)  , my set of script calculate modulo 3 reduction on every k-bonacci sequences and instead of using a mathematica wrapper like i do now to identify the periodic sequences, i wanted to do it directly in bash to gain calculation time

Comment: @Begoul, **this is a *really* inadvisable use for Bash.**  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943 for a discussion of why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array `a` of single decimal digits

```
a=(2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4)
```

then using regular expression backsubstitution, for example in `perl`

```
printf '%d' "${a[@]}" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(\d+)\1+/'
2578265354
```

Testing with an incomplete sequence

```
a=(1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2)
printf '%d' "${a[@]}" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(\d+)\1+/'
123
```

If you only want complete repeats, add a `$` line anchor to the RE, `/^(\d+)\1+$/`

---

Now, if you want to identify the *longest* subsequence that is "most nearly" repeated, that's a little trickier. For example, in the case of your 250-digit sequence, there **is** a 118-digit subsequence, repeated 2 times (with 16 characters left over), whereas your expected output is a 13-digit subsequence (repeated 19 times, with 3 digits left over). So you want an algorithm that is "greedy but not too greedy".

One (hopefully not too inefficient) way to do that would be to successively remove trailing digits until an anchored match is obtained i.e. the entire remaining sequence `s*` may be represented as `n x t` for some subsequence `t`. In perl, we can write that as a simple loop

```
perl -lne 'while (! s/^(\d+)\1+$/$1/) {chop $_}; print'
```

Testing with your 250-digit sequence:

```
a=( 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 )
```

Then

```
printf '%d' "${a[@]}" | perl -lne 'while (! s/^(\d+)\1+$/$1/) {chop $_}; print'
1102120020222
```

NOTE: this will fail to terminate if the string is exhausted before a match is found; if that's a possibility, you will need to test for that and break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: i tried this with an array of length 250 with a 13 digit periodic sequence in  ternary value (modulo 3 of Padovan sequence) , i obtained a detection of a periodic sequence of length 104 , it looks like there is a limit on the perl pipe tolerance.

Comment: but it's not enough some of my scripts generate 500 digits on big k-bonacci sequences.

Comment: Can you share these new test cases (or explain - simply - how to generate them)? I suspect it's more a matter of RE *greediness* than a limitation of the pipe - try modifying the expression to `/^(\d+?)\1+/'`.

Comment: here is the 250 array
 ( 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 )

Comment: Logically with the perl it have to find 1 1 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 0 2 2 2 but instead it result in a sequence of length 104

Comment: to generate such a sequence you have calculate first 250 terms of a Padovan like sequence with 1 1 0 in initialisation values and after take the modulo 3 reduction of each terms

Comment: a(n)=a(n-2)+a(n-3) for calculating the padovan like  sequence

Comment: The problem is you (presumably) want to identify the "longest" subsequence that is "almost" repeated. In the case of your 250-digit sequence, there **is** a 118-digit subsequence, repeated 2 times (with 16 characters left over), whereas your expected output is a 13-digit subsequence (repeated 19 times, with 3 digits left over). So you want an algorithm that is "greedy but not too greedy" - difficult to express programatically. If you trim the 3 extra digits and insist on an exact multiple (using a line anchor), the 13-digit sequence is returned as required.

Comment: OK here's an idea: `perl -lne 'while (! s/^(\d+)\1+$/$1/) {chop $_}; print'`

Comment: Well done it works , i will use this solution . Thank you very much .

Comment: @Begoul OK thanks I have updated the answer to capture the final version

Answer (score 0):

I tested this only with the inputs you provided.
assumptions - pattern to match always starts at the beginning of the array and repeats there after.

```
#!/bin/bash

#arr=(2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4  2  5  7  8  2  6  5  3  5  4  2  5  7  8  2  6  5  3  5  4)
arr=(2  5  6  3  4  2  5  6  3  4  2  5  6  3  4  2  5  6  3  4)

echo ${arr[@]}
n=${#arr[*]}
match=0
in_pattern=false

print_array()
{
  local first=$1 
  local last=$2
  local i

  for ((i=first; i<=last; i++));do
    printf "%d " ${arr[i]}
  done
  printf "\n"
}

i=0
start=0
end=0
j=$((i+1))

while (( j < n )); do
  #echo "arr[$i] ${arr[i]}  arr[$j] ${arr[j]}"
  if [[ ${arr[i]} -ne ${arr[j]} ]];then
    if [[ $match -ge 1 ]];then 
      echo "arr[$i] != arr[$j]"
      echo "pattern doesnt repeat after match # $match"
      exit 1
    fi
    ((j++))
    i=0
    in_pattern=false
    continue
  fi
  if $in_pattern ; then 
    if [[ $i -eq $end ]];then
      ((match++))
      end_match=$j
      echo "match # $match matched from $start -> $end and $start_match -> $end_match"  
      print_array $start $end
      print_array $start_match $end_match
      ((j++))
      i=0
      in_pattern=false
      continue
    fi
  else
    if [[ $match -eq 0 ]];then
      end=$((j-1))
    fi
    start_match=$j 
    in_pattern=true 
    #echo "trying to match from start $start end $end to start_match $start_match" 
  fi
  ((i++))
  ((j++))
done


output with first array -

./sequence.sh 
2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4
match # 1 matched from 0 -> 9 and 10 -> 19
2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 
2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 
match # 2 matched from 0 -> 9 and 20 -> 29
2 5 7 8 2 6 5 3 5 4 

2nd array -

/sequence.sh 
2 5 6 3 4 2 5 6 3 4 2 5 6 3 4 2 5 6 3 4
match # 1 matched from 0 -> 4 and 5 -> 9
2 5 6 3 4 
2 5 6 3 4 
match # 2 matched from 0 -> 4 and 10 -> 14
2 5 6 3 4 
2 5 6 3 4 
match # 3 matched from 0 -> 4 and 15 -> 19
2 5 6 3 4 
2 5 6 3 4
```

Comment: Hello good solution , but is it possible to return only one identified sequence with it ? i tried in commenting some echo but i still have two sequences returned ,

Comment: We increment match each time when the pattern is matched. You could just check if match is 1 and break out of the loop.

Comment: My bad , you're right , i need some sleep !! Thank you !! ^^